# change the text of label to a value from a json file, but when I run the program the label is blank

Tags: python, kivy

I am new to python and kivy. I am trying to make a small program in which the text of the label will be the value from vocab_words.json

but I am getting a blank label, and I think the inpuut() function is running even though I have made a call to it.
plz tell me what is wrong with my code and 
also how else can i change the text of the label to the value in json file.

heres my code:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.10.0')

from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class Lab(BoxLayout):
    the_value= StringProperty()     
    def  inpuut(self):
        with open('vocab_words.json') as rfile:
            data=json.load(rfile)

        the_value=data[0]['word']


class main(App):
    def build(self):
        return Lab()

m = main()
m.run()
```

heres the kivy code:

```
<Lab>:

    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            id: L
            on_text:root.inpuut()
            text: root.the_value
        Label:
            text: "something"
```

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the on_text property does not exist so it will not help. For your case there are 2 possibilities:

- Assign the text using a function:

---

***.py**

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.10.0')

from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
import json

class Lab(BoxLayout):   
    def  inpuut(self):
        with open('vocab_words.json') as rfile:
            data=json.load(rfile)
            return data[0]['word']

class main(App):
    def build(self):
        return Lab()

m = main()
m.run()
```

***.kv**

```
<Lab>:
    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            id: L
            text: root.inpuut()
        Label:
            text: "something"
```

- Or use `StringProperty`:

---

***.py**

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.10.0')

from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
import json

class Lab(BoxLayout): 
    the_value= StringProperty()     
    def  __init__(self, *args):
        BoxLayout.__init__(self, *args)
        with open('vocab_words.json') as rfile:
            data=json.load(rfile)
            self.the_value = data[0]['word']

class main(App):
    def build(self):
        return Lab()

m = main()
m.run()
```

***.kv**

```
<Lab>:
    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            id: L
            text: root.the_value
        Label:
            text: "something"
```